# Best way to link two worksheets in excel- vba

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am looking for the best way to "link" two worksheets together. I have a main worksheet where information and data is added and then I would like to have two basic worksheets that draws columns from main spreadsheet. Whenever changes are made to the main sheet, they will also occur in the other two sheets. I was thinking of trying to activate a macro which automates hitting ctrl or shift and the two tabs like the below

```
sheets (Array("Main", "Summary")).select
```

But this failed to work as well. Its too much information for vlookups or anything like that so if anyone knows a way to have changes that occur in one sheet effect multiple other ones it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Comment: How does VBA link them, when you record a macro, do the CTRL+Click on the sheets, then change a value? What else have you tried? Is that all the code you have?

Comment: Would you be able to share your full code? It might make it easier to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What I meant by that was I recorded a macro to see what the code looks like when you hold either ctrl or shift and click on a tab that you want to link. I was going to try to acitvate that code by using Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) whenever there was a change in the main sheet. I was kinda stumped for ideas on how to do this but I guess as I look at it again I could just keep the sheets all linked to the Main Sheet and hide certain rows I don't need. Unless anyone has any other ideas.

Comment: @VBAPete  I don't have any code because I am not really sure what direction I should go. Linking the sheets by doing ctrl + clicking on the sheet you want to link does not stay linked. So I am back to square one unfortunately.  Just looking for the most efficient way to have changes in the Main sheet occur in two other sheets. Rows may be added or moved so I don't think formulas in cells is the best way to do it. Not even sure there is a good solution using VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the [worksheet.Change](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm) event for that. Something simple like the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = Target
End Sub
```

Will copy the value on every cell change from one sheet to another (the code goes in the sheet's private module).